# Geometry/Programming- Draw An Equilateral Triangle Given One Point And A Desired Rotation

Tags: geometry, triangles, rotations

I feel this question has a stronger mathematical basis than strictly computer science.

I am currently drawing an equilateral triangle given its center and its radius like so.

[image: First triangle]

I would like to tweak the function to be able to draw another (given a slightly smaller radius) equilateral triangle with its "peak" perpendicular to a midpoint of any of the sides of the first triangle as shown below.

[image: Second trangle]

Here is the code I am currently using to draw the first triangle.

```
import sys
import pygame
import math


class Point2D:
    def __init__(self, xP, yP):
        self.x = xP
        self.y = yP

    def point(self):
        return self.x, self.y


def drawCircumscribedTriangle(center, radius, window):
    xoffset = math.cos(math.pi/6) * radius
    yoffset = math.sin(math.pi/6) * radius

    pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255),
                     (center.x, center.y - radius), (center.x + xoffset, center.y + yoffset))
    pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255),
                     (center.x + xoffset, center.y + yoffset), (center.x - xoffset, center.y + yoffset))
    pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255),
                     (center.x - xoffset, center.y + yoffset), (center.x, center.y - radius))

pygame.init()

#create the screen
screenWidth = 640
screenHeight = 480
rad = 20
centerPoint = Point2D(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
drawCircumscribedTriangle(centerPoint, rad, window)

#draw it to the screen
pygame.display.flip()

#input handling (somewhat boilerplate code):
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          sys.exit(0)
```

What would be a good way to not only draw based on a "peak" point and rotation, but also, upon drawing the desired triangle, return a list of the angles of that triangle's sides so that subsequent calls could be made drawing more triangles with their peaks oriented similarly inside the one that was just drawn?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

After writing the desired program, here is one of the images I have created!

[image]

Comment: ok, I don't fully understand this question!

Comment: What part would you like me to further explain?

Comment: hmm, I'm confused you want different ways of specifing triangles. or you just want code that achieves the above image?

Comment: I mean are you trying to create a fractal out of triangles? like you want four triangles each attached to another middle of the triangle drawn before and all a bit smaller?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to achieve the fractal effect you just described above.

Comment: Although!- The function should also be able to produce both of the above images.

Comment: k then I know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this answer is a bit lame but anyway.

To achieve what you are searching for you need just two functions

1. A function that draw a triangle with a given corner point and a rotation and a radius lets call this one `drawTriangle`
2. A function that draws supsequent triangles `drawMoreTriangles`

The problem I ran into when I wanted to create the second part (after getting pygame work again) was that you your triangle drawing function does not work with any rotation but just with a very specific one ($\frac{\pi}{6}$).
I noticed this after implementing part 2!

The Problem here is that your `Point2D` class has really less functionality to work with what you need is a class like this:

```
class Point2D:
   def __init__(self, x,y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y

   def __add__(self, obj):
       """ This Function will translate a Point """
       self.x = obj.x
       self.y = obj.y

   def rotate(self, arc):
       """ This function will rotate by arc around (0,0) """
       sa = math.sin(arc)
       ca = math.cos(arc)

       x = ca * self.x - sa * self.y
       self.y = sa * self.x + ca * self.y
       self.x = x
```

Now you can implement your triangle (part 1) really easy:

```
def drawTriangle(window, center, radius, rotation):
    corner = Point2D(radius, 0)

    pointlist = [None]

    for i in range(3):
        pointlist[i] = [int(corner.x+center.x), int(corner.y+center.y)]

        if i == 2:
           break

        # Rotate the corner by 60 degrees
        corner = corner.rotate(math.pi/3)        


    pygame.draw.polygon(window, color, pointlist, width)
```

Now you can also easily achieve (part 2), by using the above function for drawing triangles (if it works did not test yet) and using rotation and translation!

Gonna post a bit more if I've got more time!

Comment: I actually buckled down last night and wrote something very similar to this only to come back and see this answer! Thank you for taking the time to write this. Due to the similar nature to what I ended up doing, I'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: thx! yeah such vecotor code is always the first step to experimenting with fractals! nice done!1!